# Ubuntu 16.04 : Different partitions for root and home, but files in home occupy memory in both

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, home-directory

When installing Ubuntu 16.04 on a server, I created different partitions for root (`/`) and home (`/home`). The root partition is 15GB and home is 40GB. I had to upload a large amount of files to the server but I got the error message that root is running out of free space. I found it strange, because I uploaded the files into the `/home` partition. When I checked the file system I saw that the files in `/home` occupy space in `/` and in `/home` too even though these are different partitions.

I tried everything but the problem is still persistent. What is the solution for this problem? How could I make the files occupy space only in `/home`?

The output of `df -h` is:

```
udev            1,8G     0  1,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           369M   39M  330M  11% /run
/dev/sda8        14G   13G  593M  96% /
tmpfs           1,8G  352K  1,8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,8G     0  1,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda9        47G  7,8G   36G  18% /home
tmpfs           369M   68K  369M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           369M  8,0K  369M   1% /run/user/108
```

The output of `lsblk` is:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 136,7G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   449M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  91,4G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0 168,9G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0   7,5G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda8   8:8    0    14G  0 part /
└─sda9   8:9    0    47G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 111,7G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The output to `du --human --max-depth=2 /` (only the relevant parts) is:

```
144M    /opt/teamviewer
144M    /opt
7,4G    /root/.local
7,4G    /root
41M /var/www
106M    /var/cache
842M    /var
7,8G    /home/t-hr
7,8G    /home
207M    /lib/modules
123M    /lib/firmware
384M    /lib
54M /boot
40M /usr/sbin
250M    /usr/bin
1,1G    /usr/share
2,1G    /usr/lib
120M    /usr/src
3,6G    /usr
21G /
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: What are you using to check the space in `/` and in `/home`?

Comment: Can you post evidence that "the files in /home occupy space in / and in /home too even though these are different partitions". It would be interesting to see.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `df -h`; `mount`; and `lsblk`

Comment: I checked it in system information and it is visible in the result of df -h. I uploaded around 8 GB data into /home/user. After checking the free space this amount disappeared from / and from /home too.

Comment: Could you please bind-mount the root file system to a different location (`sudo mkdir -p /mnt/root && sudo mount -B / /mnt/root`) and include a list of the size of the content of `/mnt/root/home` (`LC_ALL=POSIX du -xB1 -h /mnt/root/home`)? Thanks.

Comment: The result : 4.0K /mnt/root/home

Comment: And you're an 8 rep user already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably running into is temp space:

Depending on the methodology of uploading and size of the files, these files might first be created in the root partition in `/tmp` and once upload is completed there, transferred to `/home`.  As rebooting removes all files from `/tmp` you wouldn't know what's happening...

(as you don't know where it comes from and where it goes to, I suspect you just reboot and the problem goes away until you run out of space again and reboot again)

**Edit:**

And don't forget to clean out your `/root/.local`  **:-D ;-)**